# The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.google.com' using Recaptcha

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha, recaptcha

**I use Recaptcha for my ASP.NET site. Everything okay in development environment, but when i public to production, I got this error:**

```
The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.google.com'
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.google.com'

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.google.com']
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +5322142
   Recaptcha.RecaptchaValidator.Validate() in D:\recaptcha-repo-dotnet\library\RecaptchaValidator.cs:134
   Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl.Validate() in D:\recaptcha-repo-dotnet\library\RecaptchaControl.cs:332
   System.Web.UI.Page.Validate() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.Validate(String validationGroup) +8740369
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +84
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Answer (score 5):

Your webhost does not allow your server to connect to other computers.

Ask them to change that, or switch to a better host.